# Cartesian Coordinates and Geometry

Tags: geometry, soft-question

By introducing the notion of "Groups", it became much clear, whether polynomial equations in one variable are solvable by radicals or not.

Come in Geometry. It has long history, and much much before Descarte, it had been developed too. Descarte introduced "coordinates" to make the subject-Geometry more transparent.

But even before Descarte, there could be some natural problems in geometry, which were left unsolved. (As in Algebra, the problem of solving equations by radicals was unsolved before Galois, but get solved by the notion of group.)

My question is, *does the notion of coordinate system helped to solve old problems in Geometry?*

Comment: think in celestial mechanics, like in mercury's motion, after and before of Riemannian's geometry

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system

Comment: There is an example close to your "theory of equations" example. Coordinatization was crucial in settling the classical problems about the trisection of the angle and the duplication of the cube.

Comment: @Andre: This is one good point.

Comment: But it is a minor point. The whole edifice of the calculus depends on coordinatization, though Newton managed to write up his basic theory of motion of the planets in purely geometric language.

Comment: That means, coordinatization made geometry "transparent", isn't it? I am also concerning "how it helped to get solved old problems?" (You have mentioned a point.)

Comment: There were old problems about quadratures that became accessible (Fermat, Roberval, others) once the machinery of coordinate geometry was available.

Comment: The question of whether the parallel postulate could be proved from other basic axioms was shown to be "No" by using co-ordinate systems to describe surfaces that were models for non-Euclidean geometry. In particular a "saddle-shaped" surface to model hyperbolic geometry.